# Returning Data with AngularJS - Bootstrap Modal Confirmation Factory

Tags: angularjs

I am wondering how to get data to be returned from a prompt/confirmation factory I created.

Everything else is working - modal is being displayed propertly etc. Right now when you click confirm it is logging "true" in the console - but no data is being returned.

Here is my factory

```
angular
  .module('app:Admin')
  .factory('NotificationService', function ($modal, $alert) {
    return {
      alert: function (data) {
        $alert(data);
      },
      prompt: function (data) {

        var promptModal = $modal({
          controller: promptController,
          content: data.content,
          title: data.title,
          templateUrl: 'promptModal.html',
          show: true
        });

        //promptModal.$promise.then(promptModal.show);
        //promptController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];

        function promptController($scope, $rootScope) {
          $scope.confirm = function () {
            console.log('true');
            return true;
          }
        }

      }
    }
  });
```

Here is my ng-click function on the delete button

```
$scope.removeGateway = function (index) {
  var data = {
    'title': 'Are you sure?',
    'content': 'Deleting this gateway cannot be undone.',
  }
  if (NotificationService.prompt(data)) {
    $scope.gatewayItems.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Here is my modal code

```
.modal(tabindex='-1', role='dialog')
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        button.close(type='button', ng-click='$hide()') ×
        h4.modal-title(ng-bind="title")
      .modal-body
        p(ng-bind="content")
      .modal-footer
        button.btn.btn-default(type='button', ng-click='$hide()') Close
        button.btn.btn-danger(type='button', ng-click='confirm(); $hide()') Delete
```

Comment: I am using angularstrap - I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer from a contributor on the AngularStrap github page.

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1505